# Storing HTML data in csv and processing using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am scraping urls and storing complete html data as pandas dataframe to store as csv file and clean.

**Code 1**

```
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url_list = ["https://www.flagstaffsymphony.org/event/masterworks-v-saint-saens-and-bruckner/",
"https://www.berlinerfestspiele.de/de/berliner-festspiele/programm/bfs-gesamtprogramm/programmdetail_341787.html",
"https://www.seattlesymphony.org/en/concerttickets/calendar/2021-2022/21bar3"]


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver')
url_data = []
columns = ['url_list','data']
for URL in url_list:
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    data = driver.page_source
    row_data = [URL,data]
    url_data.append(row_data)
html_data = pd.DataFrame(url_data, columns = ['urllist', 'data'])
html_data["parsedata"] = BeautifulSoup(str(html_data["data"]), "lxml").text
cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
html_data["cleandata"] = re.sub(cleanr, '', str(html_data["parsedata"]))
```

But after cleaning html_data["cleandata"] gives some garbage values and not the cleaned data. When tried to clean as individual url it works. How to clean this html data which is stored in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beautiful soup parser works on a text string, but you've passed a pandas series instead when you do `BeautifulSoup(str(html_data["data"]), ...)`

The fix is simply to apply the function row-wise to parse and clean the text individually

```
html_data = pd.DataFrame(url_data, columns = ['urllist', 'data'])
html_data["parsedata"] =  html_data.data.apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml").text)
cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
html_data["cleandata"] = html_data.parsedata.apply(lambda x: re.sub(cleanr, '', x))
```

Also, I would recommend that you parse and clean before appending to your list `url_data` to create the dataframe `html_data`:

```
cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
for URL in url_list:
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    cleaned_data = re.sub(cleanr, '', soup.text)
    url_data.append([URL, cleaned_data])

html_data = pd.DataFrame(url_data, columns = ['urllist', 'cleandata'])
```